# Uncaught Reference Error: data is not defined with Codeigniter and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, console.log

I downloaded and implemented bootstrap admin template on a CodeIgniter project I am working on but unfortunately, some .js functions are not working on the template which worked before, after implemented it on the CodeIgniter environment.

Console shows below errors on the js files, and However, I went through many solutions which were given here and other forums but none of them did not answer for my problem. It would be grated help some on help me to fix this!

[image: Console Screenshot]

I already changed the order of the jquery and bootstrap files also implement the js file on the  tag, however, results remained same.

Comment: You can't load your jquery file because it can't find the host cater2.tecexperts.com

Comment: view source and go through and resolve all the issues where the js/css isn't linked to something that exists/correct path.

Comment: @aynber that is not the problem

Comment: @Alex I checked all js/css files . everything is linked properly

Comment: Well, it *is* a problem, if you look at the 2nd error. `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED` sounds like it could not load the jQuery file.

Comment: it **cant** be because that is essentially what your error says

Answer (score 0):

**net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED** occurs when there’s an internet connection error or a firewall issue with your network connection setting. Some solutions here https://www.orduh.com/err-name-resolution-failed-fix-solution/